# How to open and edit mdf sql server database files on linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, mdf

How to open and edit mdf sql server database files on linux?

I use ubuntu!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of December 2016, there is a SQL Server version for Linux. The recommended approach would be to run SQL Server from the official Docker image:

- https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/
- https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-tools/

Then it would be as simple as running SQL scripts against your database. There even exists a VS Code plugin for managing your databases: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-mssql.

Answer (score -16):

Format hard disc, install Windows, install sql server, load databases (hint: mdf i not enough, you also may need the LDF file), then modify data as appropriate.

MDF files are quite complex internally and it i not as easy as editing them, sorry. They are SQL Server specific, so you will need SQL Server.